# Function to recalculate shipping costs on subscriptions after renewal with Automatewoo

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've got a funky plugin that was custom made that adds a new random product from a group that a customer subscribes to.

Problem is, that the shipping doesn't change depending on which product is selected, it stays with whatever was chosen initially.

Rather than paying more money to redevelop something that might already exist, is there any code that will recalculate shipping costs based on the item in the subscription? I have automatewoo, so could use a custom function from that and run it after a subscription payment has completed, I just don't know how to code it.

Any support appreciated!

Jono.

Comment: I think what I need is a function to recalculate shipping method based on items in purchase on subscription renewal. Easy to find functions for recalculating the cart, but not subscription renewal.

Comment: On the whole, requests for code or plugin recommendations are considered off-topic because it is almost impossible to give a definitive answer.